# search and typeahead in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In the following [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/WsnDP/21/), The list of location is parsed from the jSON object and shown. I would like to add a search and a type ahead functionality to it. The following code is not working.

```
var sourceArr = [];
for (x in data.sessions) {
    sourceArr.push(data.sessions[x].ID);
}

$(".search").typeahead({
    source: sourceArr
});

$(".search").keyup(function () {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    $(".findsession-list li").map(function (index, value) {
        $(value).toggle($(value).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have a look here : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what do you expect from typeahead but you should use `local` instead of `source`:

```
$(".search").typeahead({
    local: sourceArr
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/WsnDP/22/

Comment: I use typeahead, so that if the list is long the user can easily locate the id. But not sure when I press enter once the suggestion is shown, I am not redirected to the same ID.